# Ho do i write the SQL concat function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Hello Everyone: I have a table with column names below :

```
Select * from Table
```

**Column1 :**
California area Report

**Column2 :**
California Beach Program

**Column3 :**
John Doe

Here is my query: But it's giving me an error :

```
Select concat('Good Morning',' ',Column3, ':',

'Attached please find '+datename(month, dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))+' +'Year(Getdate()+' report for review. Please direct reporting questions to Dev@gmail.com.'

,'Report Name:','+Column1+'

,'Program name:','+Column2+',

'Kindest regards,
California Team
Director of Team') as FullMessage from Table
```

Below is the format of how I need this column : RESULT

> Good Morning John Doe:
>
> Attached please find the August 2020 report for review. Please direct
> reporting questions to Dev@gmail.com.'
>
> Report Name: California Area Report
>
> Program name: California Beach Program
>
> Kindest regards,
>
> California Team
>
> Director of Team

Comment: Would it be better to pull the information and build your message in code?  What method are you using to send the email?

Comment: I will be using this in SSRS data driven subscription to send email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
Select FullMessage = 'Good Morning ' + Column3 + ':' + CHAR (13) + CHAR (10) +
'Attached please find the '+ datename(month, dateadd(month,-1,getdate())) + ' ' + convert(varchar(4), Year(Getdate())) + ' report for review. Please direct reporting questions to Dev@gmail.com.' + CHAR (13) + CHAR (10) +
'Report Name: ' + Column1 + CHAR (13) + CHAR (10) +
'Program name: ' + Column2 + CHAR (13) + CHAR (10) +
'Kindest regards, ' + CHAR (13) + CHAR (10) +
'California Team' + CHAR (13) + CHAR (10) +
'Director of Team' 
from Table
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works, How do I create the carriage return and line feed?  char (13) + char(10) was supposed is doing it but I need a tab space from Report Name to Kindest regards.

Comment: @user9273914 char(9) = TAB character, here is a table of all of the character codes: https://www.ascii-code.com/

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Server you can concatenate strings using the `+` operator, as you've done in the later part of your query. You can use it throughout it:

```
SELECT 'Good Morning ' + Column3 + ':' -- rest of your query....
```